# jQuery ClearInterval not working when multiple setInterval clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Here is a simple jQuery Slider, and I am going to start it by clicking on `Play` Button throught setting up `interval = setInterval(updateDiv,1000);` Interval to change slides in every 1 second, and i am clearing Interval (Pause Slider) by `clearInterval(interval);` through `Pause` Button.

But the problem is I am facing that if user clicked multiple time on play button then slider animation goes crazy in changing slides and after that also `clearInterval(interval);` function not working. Why ?

Can i know the solution.

**MY WHOLE CODE IS:**

```js
var interval;
var interval = false;
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

function updateDiv() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(600)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(400)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}
$(".play").click(function() {
  interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 1000);
});
$(".pause").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow2 {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#slideshow2>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
------
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button> -------

<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried simply calling `clearInterval(interval);` before `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the user clicks on ".play" another setInterval is created, and the `interval` variable only contains the last one. So, if there's already an interval going on you need either to clear it or to prevent the user to start again.

This is a working solution:

```js
var interval;
var interval = false;
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

function updateDiv() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(600)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(400)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
}
$(".play").click(function() {
  if(!interval){
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 1000);
  }
 
});
$(".pause").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = false;
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#slideshow>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow2 {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#slideshow2>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
------
<button class="play">play</button>
<button class="pause">pause</button> -------

<div id="slideshow">
  <div>
    <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Davide Carlier sir plz check this plz plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042321/after-content-update-from-ajax-jquery-not-work-properly